# XmlReader - read xml with colons in tag names

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I have very complex XML that I need to read with `XmlReader`.
The elements in the xml are as the following:

```
<log:event>
   <ev:logger>some text</ev:logger>
   <ev:line>24</ev:line>
   <ev:ex>
      <ev:levelone>some message</ev:levelone>
      <ev:leveltwo>some other message</ev:leveltwo>
   </ev:ex>
</log:event>
```

`XmlReader` will not know how to read this since it does not have name space definition on each  xml tag.
I would have done that programmatically (appending namespace to the strings), but the file is huge and I its impossible.
(I dont control the file creation).
Any suggestion how can that file be read as xml without namespacing?

Thanks!

Comment: No. File is not correct XML document when you use undefined namespaces. Don't expect XML Parser to parse incorrect XML document.

Comment: Those are colons, not semi-colons - and without the namespace aliases, it's simply not a valid XML document. Even though you don't *control* the file creation, you should still complain that they're not generating valid XML. However, you can add namespace aliases at the root element, if you know all the prefixes used.

Comment: @JonSkeet - That's good news, I am controlling the root element. can you provide an example how can I let the reader know about all the usecases? (`ev:logger, ev:line, ev:ex` and such) thanks

Comment: @SexyMF: Just have `xmlns:ev="http://someurl"` - or whatever URI you want, basically. Use a different URI for each namespace alias. The *element* nmaes (logger, line, ex etc) don't matter - it's only the namespace aliases that you're interested in. But how come you're in control of the root element but nothing else? This sounds very odd, and you'd be *much* better off getting whoever's producing the file to produce real XML instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I can just append root element, but since it huge file, its not very clever to do string.Replace and remove the `:`. ill probably get out of memory very soon (-:

Answer (score 0):

You can still append namespaces, just read the file into memory and manipulate it there. I do it with several XML-based API's from machine manufacturers that doesn't comply with XML standards to make it easier to read with normal xml parsers

Comment: That is not posible, I can only manipulate the root element, as I told you, the file is huge. i am in a danger of out of memory exception

Comment: Then you're not doing it right. I handle files up to 2gb without any kind of memory exception. This IS possible. You're probably trying to do this via the XmlReader itself